# How could I make "required" different for item[0] and other items

Tags: json, jsonschema

One basic question. I'm not so good with json and json-schema.

This is the json that i want and that i gonna parse.

```
"Struct": [
 
            {
 
                "Name": "toto",
 
                "Status": "status1",
 
                "Atouts": [
 
                {
 
                    "Name": "atout1",
 
                    "Value": "X"
 
                },
 
                ]
 
            },
 
            {
 
                "Name": "tata",
 
                "Status": "status2"
 
            }
}
```

Here I just want to have for the first id of "Struct" -> "Name", "Status" and "Atouts" as required. And others id (after the first one) only "Name" and "Status" as required.

This is my current schema :

```
"struct": {
 
      "type": "array",
 
      "items": {
 
        "$ref": "#/definitions/struct_t"
 
      }
 
    }
 
 
 
"struct_t": {
 
  "type": "object",
 
  "required": [
 
    "Name",
 
    "Status",
 
    "Atouts"
 
 
  ],
```

Here we can see that "Atouts" would be required for all id of Struct :(.

Thank you and sorry if this question is very basic !

Answer (score 0):

You can use json schema tuple validation for that. The `"items"` does not have to be an object. It can be an array as well, with a list of subschemas defined. It means that the n-th item of the json array should be valid against the n-th subschema of items. For the indexes for which there is no subschema, you can use the `"additionalItems"`. So now you need a single-element array for `"items"` and define `additionalItems"` as well:

```
"struct": {
   "type": "array",
   "items": [
        {
           "required": [ "Name", "Status", "Atouts"]
        }
    ],
    "additionalItems": {
       "required": [ "Name", "Status"]
    }
}
```

(you can refactor it to use `"$ref"` if you need)